# What's the best way to get data into a SlickGrid that is running in a .NET browser control on mono?

Tags: javascript, html, mono, webbrowser-control, slickgrid

The browser control is not fetching data from a URL -- it comes from the .NET side of the application.

I keep running into stability issues somewhere in the mono-libgluezilla-mozilla chain.

Initially I tried making a JavaScript call (using browser.Document.InvokeScript) to my own function that would do the work of updating that cell in the SlickGrid.  I figured that the large amount of .NET-to-script calls were contributing to the stability problem, so I then changed the code such that a whole row could be updated with one script call (passing a JSON string).  But the stability issues remain.  It seems that I cannot be making script calls at the same time as I am clicking around in the SlickGrid, or the whole application seg-faults with something like this:

```
    mono() [0x48b231]
    mono() [0x4d48af]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf2e0) [0x7feeb2af32e0]
    /usr/lib64/libgluezilla.so(+0x108cf) [0x7feea96b58cf]
    /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x1f3) [0x7feeb314ea93]
    /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x41270) [0x7feeb314f270]
    /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_iteration+0x70) [0x7feeb314f510]
    /usr/lib64/xulrunner-1.9.2.6/libxul.so(+0xc5a5e3) [0x7feea35215e3]
    /usr/lib64/xulrunner-1.9.2.6/libxul.so(+0xc5a689) [0x7feea3521689]
    /usr/lib64/xulrunner-1.9.2.6/libxul.so(+0xd747c0) [0x7feea363b7c0]
    /usr/lib64/xulrunner-1.9.2.6/libxul.so(+0xd494a1) [0x7feea36104a1]
    /usr/lib64/xulrunner-1.9.2.6/libxul.so(+0xc5a596) [0x7feea3521596]
    /usr/lib64/xulrunner-1.9.2.6/libxul.so(+0xc485d6) [0x7feea350f5d6]
    /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_context_dispatch+0x1f3) [0x7feeb314ea93]
    /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x41270) [0x7feeb314f270]
    /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0(g_main_loop_run+0x195) [0x7feeb314f8f5]
    /usr/lib64/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0(gtk_main+0xa7) [0x7feeada3e777]
    /usr/lib64/libgluezilla.so(_Z11gtk_startupPv+0x39) [0x7feea96b7549]
    /usr/lib64/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x67e86) [0x7feeb3175e86]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x6a4f) [0x7feeb2aeaa4f]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7feeb25fd82d]
```

I even tried throttling my script calls (10ms per call).  Still crashes.

The problem appears to lessen when there are fewer columns in the SlickGrid, but still occurs with 9 columns.

There are 150 rows in my table.

Is there another way to get data from .NET to JavaScript?  If so, perhaps the mono+libgluezilla+SlickGrid trio will handle it better.

Comment: To clarify, the crash only happens when I am making script calls and clicking around in the grid (even if the script calls pass no data and do no work).

Comment: I suspect that it's a threading problem.  But rather than dive too deeply into the bug, I'd really like to hear that I'm updating the grid in a stupid way and there is a better option available.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering why I'm displaying the grid in HTML instead of a native .NET control, it's because both ListView and DataGridView are very slow in mono.  Mono has been nothing but a headache.

Comment: Also, I am using the SlickGrid DataView (so I get filtering).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick seems to be to limit the script calls to something very slow, like one call per 100ms. In order to go that slow, I have to pack the entire contents of the grid into a JSON string and update the whole thing at once. It still crashes sometimes, but this is the best solution I could come up with.  Giving up on mono now.